# Select Columns from multiple tables - Django

Tags: django, django-orm

I am trying to select all the columns from one table and only a single column from the second table using the Django ORM.The two tables are related by a foreign key but the column in the second table which i want, is not related, so using select_related doesn't work.

I used

```
    FirstTable.objects.filter().values("All first table columns separated by a comma","second tablename__column name")
```

and this worked fine. Since, the columns are very large in number, i do not want to list all of them in "values". So, i am looking for an easy way to do this.

Thanks for your help

EDIT:

Thanks for the help! I was able to get it working by using annotate like the following.

```
FirstTable.objects.filter().annotate(variable_name=F("SecondtableFieldName"))
```

Comment: Have you looked at prefetch_related?

Answer (score -2):

You Can use the extra method in this.

```
FirstTable.objects.filter().extra("write down here what every yo want")
```